# Calculating limit without using logarithms or exponentials

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, limits

Hello everyone I really need to calculate this limit without using $\ln$ or $\log$ or exponential function. Here it is: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[n\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt[n]x}\right)-n(\sqrt[n]x-1)\right]$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq2$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x>1$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put $f_n(x)=x^{1/n}$. As $x>1$ there exists $c\in ]1,x[$ such that $\displaystyle f_n(x)-f_n(1)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{x-1}{c^{1-1/n}}\leq (x-1)/n$. So we have $0<n(x^{1/n}-1)\leq x-1$. Now your expression is $\displaystyle u_n=-n\frac{(x^{1/n}-1)^2}{x^{1/n}}$.

We have, as $x^{1/n}\geq 1$:
$$|u_n|\leq (x-1)\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{x^{1/n}}\leq (x-1)( x^{1/n}-1)\leq \frac{(x-1)^2}{n}$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $x^{1/n} = 1+ a_n.$ Our expression equals

$$(1/x^{1/n} - 1)na_n.$$

You know $x^{1/n} \to 1.$ What can you say about $na_n?$